# subquery in an IN statement does't work properly

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm a having a problem with this query, the subquery by itself works perfectly, but when I put it in the IN statement, the result is completely unexpected, any of the rows contain the id's from the subquery. so my question is, what I'm doing wrong? thanks for your help!

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_2_temp_elements`
WHERE  subtemplateID IN (
     SELECT bridge.sub_templates
     FROM `wp_2_templates` AS templates
     INNER JOIN `wp_2_b_templates_sub_templates` AS bridge ON templates.id = bridge.templates
     WHERE templates.parent = 928
     OR templates.id = 928
     ORDER BY templates.id DESC
)
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more of how it is failing? I don't understand "_any of the rows contain the id's from the subquery_" It ought to work exactly as written (if the subquery works on its own) except that you should not be placing an `ORDER BY` inside the `IN ()` subquery. Do your ordering on the outermost set.

Comment: I remove the ORDER BY and I got the same result as before. from the subquery I got a list of all subtemplateID that I need, I run this subquery by itself and the list that I get works just fine, but when I  put it inside the subquery no row with the subtemplateID match the list that I was expected and all of them has the same subtemplateID id

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you don't really want the `join` in the inner query.  Just a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM `wp_2_temp_elements` templates
WHERE  subtemplateID IN (
     SELECT bridge.sub_templates
     FROM `wp_2_b_templates_sub_templates` AS bridge
     WHERE templates.id = bridge.templates and
           (templates.parent = 928 OR templates.id = 928)
)
ORDER BY templates.id DESC;
```

The `order by` also makes no sense in the subquery.

Comment: I got this Error "#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'ON WHERE templates.id = bridge.templates and (templates.parent ' at line 5"

Comment: Remove the word "on".  I didn't even see it there.